# EF Core user-defined function for PostgreSQL extension

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

I currently have Sql mapped function which I want to map as a user-defined function:

```
context.Structures.FromSqlInterpolated($"select * from \"Structures\" where \"Molfile\" @ ({search}, '')::bingo.sub")
```

The where method comes from a PostgreSQL extension called [Bingo](https://lifescience.opensource.epam.com/bingo/user-manual-postgres.html#substructure-search).

I don't understand from the docs how I should be doing that. Here's an example of the things I've tried:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Structure>().ToTable("Structure");
        builder.HasDbFunction(typeof(ChemistryContext).GetMethod(nameof(Sub), new[] { typeof(string) })).HasName("bingo.sub");
    }


    public IQueryable<Structure> Sub(string search)
        => FromExpression(() => Sub(search));
```

This particular code above fails because there's no `bingo.sub` user function.

Thank you for some inputs on how this should be done!

Comment: what exactly is the error that you are getting?Also, the problem is that bingo.sub is not recognized, question is why? I can't tell because I don't see the rest of the code, but it seems to me that you are missing something

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1487 it may help you

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It says "function bingo.sub(text) does not exist" (or "function bingo.sub(text, text) does not exist", which I also tried).
Do you happen to know what the "@" sign is called?
All the typical examples (including yours) don't use a function like this in a WHERE clause ("column" @ function), so maybe mapping this is somehow special or impossible...

Comment: I can see that the problem that you have is clear to me, but unfortunately I don't have enough code to assess it properly. So I ha ve a few questions, first of all, have you checked that the function (method) bingo.sub has been created? Also, usually, @ is placed before the name of a variable in SQL, I don't see the variable, is it possible that it is not creating the function because of that? have you checked that the sql query works?

Comment: Thanks again for your reply Iria. The SQL works, yes. I've tested it both manually and through the mapped SQL in .NET Core. Also, `bingo.sub` is created from the extension I linked in the main question, not through EF Core code, so yeah this exists.

Comment: if it tells you that it does not exist, and you have tested it, then the problem is the visibility of the method, what if you encapsulate bingo.sub add a few messages for debugging and see if you can access this.

Comment: Hmm the visibility makes no sense when I can run the `FromSqlInterpolated` but can't map it, right? (I'm running the `FromSqlInterpolated` with the same user & rights)